# Multi-GPU Tensorflow for SeqGAN

Tags: tensorflow

We tried to train SeqGAN on two GTX-1060 with Tensorflow but found it only use /GPU:0 for training. After checking the log_device_placement, all the layers are connected to GPU:0 and no layer use GPU:1.

After searching, it looks like we need to deploy layers into multi-GPU by my self.(But we are not sure if this is correct.)

Our question is that could we deploy our training job likes this:

- Suppose BATCH=64
- GPU:0: handle 0-31 BATCH data
- GPU:1: handle 32-63 BATCH data
- Summarize the results with either devices.

Does this support by Tensorflow? Shall we need to implement it by ourselves?

SeqGAN: https://github.com/LantaoYu/SeqGAN

Log: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-fFMM_3Dj9Ja3Vzckh2TmdlNGM

Answer (score 0):

This is supported by TensorFlow and you can find it in the [CIFAR-10 tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/deep_cnn). Look through the code `cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py` over [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/) as well.